# How to install and configure the plug-in client Social Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I need to install the client plug-in TFS but I found online guides only for the server side.

I have already installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=329) & install it.

Then use this [Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to connect to TFS Server.